# A question regarding networking

Tags: iphone

I have to communicate with server
I have to  questions in my mind

1>code that connect to server
2>code that try to connect to server untill and unless connection establish with server.

Comment: Can you be more specific as there is no questions supplied!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [iphone on rails](http://iphoneonrails.com/) and [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

I'm using both at the moment and they work like a dream.